# SkewNormalDistribution with a mean value

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, distributions

Since it got incredibly good answers the last time i posted a question, i try it again! ;-)

I programmed a chemical/physical simulation in mathematica, where i can use residence time distribution as an input parameter. No I'd like to compare different theoretical distributions. As a criteria, the distributions need to have the same mean value μ. It's easy to do it with NormalDistributions as follows:

```
dist1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.216208304, 0.0025], 10^4];

Show[Histogram[dist1, 14, "ProbabilityDensity"], AxesLabel->{"\[Tau]/s","\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(V\), \(.\)]\)/\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\),\\(3\)]\)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(s\), \(-1\)]\)"}]

HistogramList[dist1, 14, "ProbabilityDensity"]
```

Therewith i obtaine a Histogram plot where i can export the container values and size to my simulation.

[image]

More difficulties i had when i tried to create a skew distribution with the same mean value as in the normal distribution, means: 0.216208304
I tried it with the following code:

```
CSTR = RandomVariate[SkewNormalDistribution[0.216208304, 1, 1000], 10^4];
```

But the location parameter μ in the SkewNormalDistribution doesn't seems to be the mean value. If i create to mean value of the CSTR-List with Mean[CSTR], i get 1.01582 - so totally wrong.

Anybody has an idea how i can create a skew distribution with a mean value of 0.2162... ?

Thanks in advance and a happy new year!
Dani

Comment: The location $l$ of the skew normal dist. is not its mean $\mu$ - see [skew normal distribution (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution); the relation between the two is given in [Coolwater's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162947/22013).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

```
Mean[SkewNormalDistribution[loc[1, 1000, 0.216208304], 1, 1000]]
```

> 0.2162083

where

```
loc[σ_, α_, μ_] = μ - (Sqrt[2/π] σ α)/Sqrt[1 + α^2];
```

is obtained from

```
First[Solve[Mean[SkewNormalDistribution[l, σ, α]] == μ, l] // FullSimplify]
```

> $\left\{l\to \mu -\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \alpha  \sigma }{\sqrt{\alpha ^2+1}}\right\}$

Actually the code below gives a closed form for the mean when discarding simulations less than $0$. `Solve` can't determine any parameter given the other, so you need to use a numeric function like `FindRoot`.

```
expr = With[{anti = Integrate[
                      PDF[SkewNormalDistribution[a, σ, α], x] (x - a)/
                       (1 - CDF[SkewNormalDistribution[a, σ, α], 0]), x]},
  Limit[anti, x -> ∞, Assumptions -> {{(a Sqrt[1 + α^2])/(Sqrt[2] σ),
                       (a α)/(Sqrt[2] σ)} ∈ Reals, σ > 0, Sqrt[1 + α^2] > 0}] -
  Limit[anti, x -> 0] + a] // FullSimplify
```

> $\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \sigma  \left(e^{-\frac{a^2}{2 \sigma ^2}} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{a \alpha }{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)+\frac{\alpha  \text{erf}\left(\frac{a \sqrt{\alpha ^2+1}}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)}{\sqrt{\alpha ^2+1}}\right)}{4 T\left(\frac{a}{\sigma },\alpha \right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)+1}+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \alpha  \sigma }{\sqrt{\alpha ^2+1} \left(4 T\left(\frac{a}{\sigma },\alpha \right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)+1\right)}+a$

Comment: Hey Coolwater, thanks for your answer! Is it further possible to limit the minimum values to 0? A residence time less than 0 s would make sense for my problem..

Comment: @black Replace 2 parameters in `expr` by numbers and adjust the mean by the last one through `FindRoot`

Answer (score 0):

```
SeedRandom[0];

dist1 = NormalDistribution[0.216208304, 0.0025];
```

Random data drawn from the [`NormalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NormalDistribution.html)

```
data1 = RandomVariate[dist1, 10^4];
```

To find a [`SkewNormalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SkewNormalDistribution.html) that best fits the random data

```
dist2 = EstimatedDistribution[data1, SkewNormalDistribution[m, s, a]]

(* SkewNormalDistribution[0.215064, 0.0027407, 0.597653] *)
```

Since you also indicated that you want the values of the `SkewNormalDistribution` to be restricted to nonnegative values, use [`TruncatedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TruncatedDistribution.html).

Using the parameters of the `SkewNormalDistribution` (`dist2`) as initial estimates of the parameters for the `TruncatedDistribution`

```
dist3 = EstimatedDistribution[data1, 
  TruncatedDistribution[{0, Infinity}, SkewNormalDistribution[m, s, a]], 
  Transpose[{{m, s, a}, List @@ dist2}]]

(* TruncatedDistribution[{0, ∞}, 
 SkewNormalDistribution[0.215063, 0.00274102, 0.598107]] *)
```

Random data drawn from the `TruncatedDistribution`

```
data2 = RandomVariate[dist3, 10^4];

Column[{
  Show[
   Histogram[data1, 25, "PDF",
    PlotLabel -> dist1,
    ImageSize -> Large],
   Plot[Tooltip[PDF[dist1, x]], {x, Min[data1], Max[data1]}]],
  Show[
   Histogram[data2, 25, "PDF",
    PlotLabel -> dist3,
    ImageSize -> Large],
   Plot[Tooltip[PDF[dist3, x]], {x, 0, Max[data2]},
    PlotRange -> All]]}]
```

[image]

Comparing the `Mean` of the `TruncatedDistribution` with that of the `NormalDistribution`

```
Abs[Mean[data2] - Mean[dist1]]

(* 0.000020577 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can re-parametrize `SkewNormalDistribution` so that the first parameter is its mean:

```
snd[μ_, σ_, α_]:= SkewNormalDistribution[μ - Mean[SkewNormalDistribution[0, σ, α]], σ, α]

Mean[snd[μ, σ, α]]
```

> μ

```
Mean[snd[0.216208304, 1, 1000]]
```

> 0.216208304

`Variance` and `Skewness` are not affected by this reparametrization:

```
Variance[snd[μ, σ, α]] == Variance[SkewNormalDistribution[μ, σ, α]]
```

> True

```
Skewness[snd[μ, σ, α]] == Skewness[SkewNormalDistribution[μ, σ, α]]
```

> True